# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: typescript, webpack, angular5, 2sxc

I cannot compile my Angular 5 application using AOT (ng build --prod). What is the problem?

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\src'  @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-66  @
>   multi ./src/main.ts

We are developing this application to test our `dnn-sxc-angular` npm project with Angular 5. As soon as I import `ContentManagerModule` from `@2sic.com/dnn-sxc-angular`, the AOT build fails.

I ran `node_modules/.bin/ngc.cmd` but no error appeared. Is there any way of debugging the build process or getting human readable error messages?

The demo app that breaks:
https://github.com/2sic/app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev

`dnn-sxc-angular` (worked with Angular 4):
https://github.com/2sic/dnn-sxc-angular

**Project Structure**
[image]

**My Environment:**

- Windows 10
- npm: 5.6.0
- node: 8.9.3
- angular cli (local and global): 1.6.1

**The complete output of `webpack --bail`:**

> C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev>webpack --bail  11% building
>   modules 9/9 modules 0 activeModuleNotFoundError: Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\src'
>       at factoryCallback (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:276:40)
>       at factory (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:235:20)
>       at resolver (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:60:20)
>       at asyncLib.parallel (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:127:20)
>       at C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3874:9
>       at C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:473:16
>       at iteratorCallback (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:1048:13)
>       at C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:958:16
>       at C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\async\dist\async.js:3871:13
>       at resolvers.normal.resolve (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:119:22)
>       at onError (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:65:10)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at runAfter (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:158:4)
>       at innerCallback (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:146:3)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at next (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:252:11)
>       at C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\UnsafeCachePlugin.js:40:4
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at runAfter (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:158:4)
>       at innerCallback (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:146:3)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at next (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:252:11)
>       at innerCallback (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:144:11)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at next (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:249:35)
>       at resolver.doResolve.createInnerCallback (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\DescriptionFilePlugin.js:44:6)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at afterInnerCallback (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\Resolver.js:168:10)
>       at loggingCallbackWrapper (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
>       at next (C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:252:11)
>   resolve './app/app.module.ngfactory' in
>   'C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\src'   using description file:
>   C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src)
>       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration   after using description file:
>   C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src)
>       using description file: C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\package.json (relative path:
>   ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory)
>         no extension
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\src\app\app.module.ngfactory
>   doesn't exist
>         .ts
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.ts
>   doesn't exist
>         .js
>           Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>           C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\src\app\app.module.ngfactory.js
>   doesn't exist
>         as directory
>           C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev\src\app\app.module.ngfactory
>   doesn't exist
>
> C:\Projects\app-dnn-sxc-angular-dev>

Comment: any Luck.? have you got any solution .? i got the same problem.

Comment: @Developer No solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
ng build --prod --aot
```

Comment: This ended up solving our issue on the newer version of AngularCLI. Thanks.